# How to use jquery rewrite redirect url

Tags: jquery, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I created a drop down list(with javascript onchange features), I would like to rewrite the redirect url from this: http://localhost/en/abc/kk.php?CT=1 to http://localhost/abc/kk.php?lang=en&CT=1 by using jquery.

Possible to do it?

Comment: Where are those urls? Is the drop down list a menu with anchors that point to that/those urls? The information here isn't enough to form and answer.

Comment: simple you want to append `lang=en` in your query string? right

Comment: If you want to just append a lang param, you can update the `href` attribute of the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rewrite the redirect url through clientside script such as javascript itself. You need `.htaccess` file to do so.

However, if the urls `http://localhost/en/abc/kk.php?CT=1` is already present in your markup like in anchor tags

```
<a href="http://localhost/en/abc/kk.php?CT=1">Some Link Text</a>
```

Then you can use jQuery to change the value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").attr("href","http://localhost/abc/kk.php?lang=en&CT=1");
    //It is better to replace the values using pattern mathcing
});
```